# UnicodeDecodeError in pip install

Tags: python, setup.py

I am trying to upload a package to PyPI for external use, and hitting a snag when I attempt local installation.  During the cleanup phase of the `pip install`, pip is hitting a UnicodeDecodeError that is mysterious to me.  The source repo is [here](https://github.com/bwarren2/threes).

```
pip install threes==0.1.9
...
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Downloading/unpacking cookiecutter==0.7.2 (from threes==0.1.9)
Downloading cookiecutter-0.7.2.tar.gz (107kB): 107kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 274, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1173, in prepare_files
self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1320, in unpack_url
retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir, self.session)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 587, in unpack_http_url
unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 625, in unpack_file
untar_file(filename, location)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 556, in untar_file
path = os.path.join(location, fn)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

Storing debug log for failure in /home/me/.pip/pip.log
```

Has anyone seen this before?  When I `pip install` the requirements from the requirements.txt in the local project, everything works; I am not familiar enough with what pip is doing here to know what to google.

Comment: Are there any odd characters in your installation directory? Your account name?

Comment: I do not think so.  Adding the source repo to the question so other eyes can check.